# Azure will not let me swap to my new smaller OS disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Good Morning, Fellow Stack Overflow-ers,

I have a Windows 2019 DC Virtual Machine with a 127GiB OS Disk with MS Azure. The WM image is `Standard B2s (2 vcpus, 4 GiB memory)`

I want to swap this with a smaller 8GiB OS disk - having successfully created this in my portal and labelled `useastOS` - Azure is failing to allow me to swap from the previous 127GiB disk to the smaller 8GiB Disk. On the "Swap OS Disk" menu illustrated, you will see there is no option to use the `useastOS` disk.

Puzzling.

This is a managed disk and so there is no reason whatsoever as to why Azure is not giving me the option.

So my question is there any valid reason as to why Azure is not allowing me to swap to the smaller `useastOS` or is this bug within Azure that I need to make Azure aware of?

[image: Disk List]

[image: Disk Swap Menu]

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on ServerFault or SuperUser, as this is really a VM/infrastructure question, and not a programming question.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you found a solution. I don't understand how to get the vhd blob for an ubuntu installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case, confirm that you selected an operation system when you created this disk useastOS. For example, in my case it is Windows, but disk can be either Windows or Linux, when you don't select anything, Azure assumes it is a data disk, not an operation system.

[image: disk]

Comment: Actually, having said that, there's no option to select any OS on the disk creation page anyway. [Screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/wsCQvpQ/sreenshot-disk-no-os-selection-option.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes it does have a blank section under "Operating System", however because the disk is unattached that this could be why? Thanks [screenshot] (https://i.ibb.co/JKQGD6k/sreenshot-disk-no-os.png)

Comment: In those case, when you select source of disk as blob, you select your vhd file. At this moment you can choose Windows or Linux. There is no option to change it after creating. You must repeat this step to create a new disk from you vhd file and pay attention to select your correct OS, as far as I remember by default disk is "data".

Comment: Thank you, so how do I obtain my container URL or where do I find my VHD file? Why does Azure keep asking me for non-existent information?  It should not be this hard to do a simple task. I just want to create an OS disk with a smaller GiB & attach it do my existing VM - right now I feel like Azure is asking me to perform open-heart surgery on an alien.  I have made an appt with an MS engineer and I'm going to be having serious words with the way in which they develop their products and processes.
No more troubleshooting - I'm getting bored sick of it now.

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating a Managed Disk like this, there is no SO installed, it is an empty disk, that's why Azure assumes it is a data disk, not a SO disk.

[image: disk1]

Now, when you upload your VHD disk to blob storage, you can tell Azure that this disk is OS and not a data disk like this.

[image: disk2]

Looking for upload VHD to Azure blob, here it is an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image.

Your question is how to swap SO disk to a new one smaller, this is what I understood, in case you just want to add a second disk as a data disk, you can go to VM overview, from blade disk, you can add it easily.

Anyway, I hope that I could help in any :)

Comment: Thank you for your support, & I will mark your answer as correct to help others out. However, patience has snapped. If I see one more error message or if I get one more "issue" then, this computer is going to have an axe taken to it. It's much safer for everyone if some one else deals with this. I don't take very kindly to stupidity - at my work computers either do as they're told or they get thrown against a wall. Simple as. Thank you for your help though - much appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a hint for what an SO disk is?

Comment: When importing a VHD disk to Azure, you must select if this disk is SO (operation system like Windows or Linux) or it is just a data disk. In case you do not select SO and it is a VHD of Windows 10 for example you will not be able to create a VM from this disk, just attach it to a secundary disk (data disk).